# Outlook Addin Deployment

Tags: c#, deployment, outlook, add-in

Just developed a outlook addin, but now i am trying to create a setup project. i follow the tutorial from http://www.supinfo-projects.com/en/2006/add_in_outlook_2007_en/introduction/ , but when i try to install a error occurred ( Error 1001. Cannot set the security policy. --> Cannot create the security code group 'OutlookPanel'. --> The system cannot find the spetified file (exception from hresult: 0x80070002)

In the custom action in install i have
/assemblyName="OutlookPanel" /targetDir="[TARGETDIR]\"    /solutionCodeGroupName="Company.OutlookPanel"    /solutionCodeGroupDescription="Code group for OutlookPanel"    /assemblyCodeGroupName="OutlookPanel"    /assemblyCodeGroupDescription="Code group for OutlookPanel" /allUsers=[ALLUSERS]

What's the problem?? can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget to add the registry keys.

Answer (score 0):

You should always write keys under HKCU instead Local Machine or Policies. The addin will load normally from HCKU.

Answer (score 0):

Add following registry keys under," HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\AddIns\YourAddinName.Connect".

Key name : LoadBehavior,
Value :"3" (always load at startup),
Value Type :  integer (DWORD).

Key name : FriendlyName, 
Value :"Product Name", 
Value Type : string.

Key name : Description,
Value :"Description",
Value Type : string.

However, you can ignore the third key.